# Curl error if server close?

Tags: php, curl

I have a question related to curl error response. For example if I am trying to access a server that is currently closed due to some reason then what response curl will return me? And what kind or error it should be for example it will be `404` or `505` or `something else` . It is a general question just for knowledge, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'server is closed'?

Comment: Make a curl call by passing random server call.

Comment: i mean if server is not running or may b i write wrong url or dont have permission to access that server something like that

Answer (score 2):

Usually if host is unavailable (site is dead) curl_error code will be:

- CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)
- CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)

It is for not successfully curl requests when `curl_exec($handle) === false`. You can get `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT` if web-server (nginx) is stopped. Error `CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST` can be returned for nonexistent urls.

---

For successfull requests you can check http status code `curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`. It can be:

- 500 (5xx) - problems with response (e.g. mysql/php problems)
- 404 - nothing found.

"don't have permission to access" - It would be e.g. 401,403 http status codes.